# Isolated Digit Recognition using HTK

Tags: speech-recognition, htk

I am experimenting isolated word recognition using HTK. So far I've built these files:

`dict` file:

```
eight           eight sp
five            five sp
four            four sp
nine            nine sp
one             one sp
sent-end        sil sp
sent-start      sil sp
seven           seven sp
six             six sp
three           three sp
two             two sp
zero            zero sp
```

`source.mlf` file:

```
#!MLF!#
"*/00F1SET0.lab"
zero
.
"*/01F1SET0.lab"
one
.
"*/02F1SET0.lab"
two
.
"*/03F1SET0.lab"
three
.
"*/04F1SET0.lab"
four
.
"*/05F1SET0.lab"
five
.
"*/06F1SET0.lab"
six
.
"*/07F1SET0.lab"
seven
.
"*/08F1SET0.lab"
eight
.
"*/09F1SET0.lab"
nine
.
```

And I keep the `0*F1SET0.wav` files inside `wav` directory of the project directory.

And `mhphones0.led` with following commands:

```
EX
IS sil sil
DE sp
```

Then I am trying to execute this command:

```
HLEd -l '*' -d dict -i models0.mlf mkphones0.led source.mlf
```

But it is showing this error:

```
  ERROR [+1230]  ReadLabId: string arg expected at line 3/col 6/char 21 in mkphones0.led
 FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HLEd
```

I don't understand what's the problem in the commands of `mkphones0.mlf` file. Please help and thanks in advance!

Comment: why is this tagged as perl?

Comment: Well, it was a mistake...edited!! A help for my particular problem will be more appreciable!

Comment: It says precisely the problem is with the file mkphones0.led It might be an issue with invisible end-of-line characters or some whitespaces. It is required to terminate that file with a new line. You need to look on this file. To get more detailed help you need to share that file as a file with dropbox or google drive and not paste it in the question. You can give a link to the file here.

Comment: Hello Sir, After your comment I ended the file with a new line and now
it is showing this error: `ERROR [+1232]  NumParts: Cannot find word . in dictionary`. This is my mkphones0.led file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ydcdoewshz6a5rs/mkphones0.led

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, at last I solve this problem by putting a newline at the end of `mkphones0.led` and adding `(etc.)` at the end of `source.mlf`. Thanks @Nikolay Shmyrev for pointing about the newline.